# Is there a way to see where the Go lexer inserts semicolons?

Tags: go, lexer

In the Go spec, the section about [semicolons](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Semicolons) says that semicolons are automatically inserted into the token stream if some rules are true.

> When the input is broken into tokens, a semicolon is automatically inserted into the token stream immediately after a line's final token if that token is
>
> ```
> an identifier
> an integer, floating-point, imaginary, rune, or string literal
> one of the keywords break, continue, fallthrough, or return
> one of the operators and punctuation ++, --, ), ], or }
> ```

Is there a way to actually see what the code looks like after this step? Just curious how the lexing is done.

To me, it seems like semicolons would end up after if statements and functions?

```
package foo;

func bar() {
  a := 1;
  if a > 0 {
  };
};
```

I'd like to actually see what happens instead of guessing though.

Comment: sounds unlikely, adding semicolons is a compiler step and the compiler doesn't output Go code.

Comment: The parsing rule is pretty clear and your example looks correct. The important point is in the first sentence. The semicolon effectively replaces the final newline in the enumerated cases; otherwise, the newline is equivalent to a space when tokenizing the text. Think about how you would interpret the code if it was written as a single line. I'm not aware of any tool that will show you the single-line equivalent with explicit semicolons. In theory such a tool could be written using the https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast package but I've never run across such a tool.